# Yolov8 segmentation task : error : torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory

Tags: memory-management, pytorch, yolov8

Helllo, i want to run a segmentation task on a custom Dataset using "Yolov8s-seg" Model.

My training hyperparameters ares :
Batch-size : 1
imgsz : 1280
Iam using a Quadro RTX 4000 (dedicated 8gb)

In the first epochs i get an error of :

`torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 812.00 MiB (GPU 0; 8.00 GiB total capacity; 5.80 GiB already allocated; 179.62 MiB free; 5.91 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation. See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF`

I tried to release cuda cache, set batch-size =-1 so it can handle it automatically, i set the pytorch cuda alloc to 4096 mb but always i get the same error

```
os.environ["PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF"] = "max_split_size_mb:4096"
```

Decreasing the img-size is not an availble option. Is there any other methode of memory managment i can use to solve this problem.

Comment: yolov8s-seg takes up to 2-3GiB for training on imgsz=1280 with batch=1. Need to find out what these 5.91 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch. Is your GPU memory available before the training? More information about the case will be helpful in analyzing the problem.